# Exit from while loop with if/else in Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, automation, cypress

I am writing a test case which requires me to reload the page `N` number of times, and compare its title for a value, if that value does not exists then break the while loop without rising error.

Below is a demo program, similar to the one that I am looking to implement.

```
/// <reference types='cypress' />

it("Visiting Google",function(){
    var webUrl = 'https://html5test.com/'
    cy.visit(webUrl)
    var loop_iter = 0
    while(loop_iter < 5)
    {
        cy.get('body:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) div.header h1:nth-child(1) > em:nth-child(2)').then(($text_data) =>{
            if($text_data.text().contains('HTML123'))
            {
                cy.log(" --> ITERATION = ",loop_iter)
                cy.reload()
            }
            else
            {
                cy.log("Unknown website")
                loop_iter = 10
            }
        })
        loop_iter += 1
    }
})
```

I need a way to break from the while loop when the else part is executed, without rising any error.

The if condition when false returns AssertionError, in such case it should execute else part.

Comment: You need to use recursion, at least that's the common pattern given by Cypress.

Comment: Take a look at [cypress-recurse](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/////cypress-recurse/). Your 'commandsFn' would be `() => cy.title()` and the 'checkFn` would be `($text_data) => $text_data.includes('HTML')`. I'm not yet sure where to fit the `cy.reload()`.

Comment: this is a demo example, I really want to use `const $val = cy.get()` and compare if $val contains string, if it fails it should exit from while

Comment: You should amend the question to show what it is you really want. Also the while loop will not work, there's plenty of info about it (some linked here).

Answer (score 0):

`cy.title()` is asynchronous (proof is, you need to use `.then()`), so, the entire `while` loop ends even before the first `.then()` triggers. That's how asynchronism works.

You need another approach :

```
it("Visiting Google", async function () {
    var webUrl = 'https://html5test.com/'
    cy.visit(webUrl)

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // You can't await in a 'while' loop

        const $text_data = await cy.title();

        if ($text_data.includes('HTML')) {
            cy.log(" --> ITERATION = ", i)
            cy.reload()
        }
        else {
            cy.log("Unknown website")
            break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: if I use 'const $text_data = cy.get(element)', then if statement throw AssertionError when false, need to execute else block in such situations

Comment: I didn't write `$text_data = cy.title()`, I wrote `$text_data = await cy.title()`. There's a huge difference. The first one returns an unresolved Promise, the second one the value you seek.

Comment: Just because it has a `.then()` function does not make it a Promise. `cy.title()` returns a Chainable which does not work with `await`.

Comment: `text_data.includes('HTML')` throws error in if case

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the sample recipe [Page reloads](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__page-reloads). It uses recursion as suggested in comments.

This is your code adapted to the pattern,

```js
it('reload until "HTML" disappears', () => {

  // our utility function
  const checkAndReload = (recurse_level = 0) => {

    cy.title().then(title => {
      if (title.includes('HTML') && recurse_level < 5) {

        cy.log(" --> ITERATION = ", recurse_level)
        cy.wait(500, { log: false })           // just breathe here
        cy.reload()                            // reload
        checkAndReload(recurse_level + 1)      // check again

      } else {
        cy.log("Unknown website") 
      }
    })
  }

  cy.visit('https://html5test.com/')      // start the test by visiting the page
  checkAndReload()                        // and kicking off the first check
})
```