# Break if/else block without exception Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, cypress

I need a way to run below code snippet successfully with any exceptions

```
it("Visiting Google",function(){
    var webUrl = 'https://html5test.com/'
    cy.visit(webUrl)
    var iterator = 1
    while(iterator < 5)
    {
        const $select_element = cy.get('h1 > em')
        if($select_element.contains('abcd'))
        {
            cy.log("string found")
        }
        else
        {
            cy.log('string not found')
            break
        }
        iterator += 1
    }
})
```

I need this test case to run while loop until condition in while fail, or if case condition fails and control enters to else block

Answer (score 0):

The statement `$select_element.contains('abcd')` doesn't return a true/false like your code wants. If the element is not found, the cypress will fail and stop.

What you need to do is get the value from the element, and do the comparison on that. Here is the way to do that using a closure (callback)

```
cy.get('h1 > em').then(($select_element) => {
    if($select_element.text().match('abcd')) {
        cy.log("string found")
    } else ...
})
```

But because it's in a callback, it's asynchronous, and won't work inside the loop you have.

Comment: this is a duplicate question from same author, see [Exit from while loop with if/else in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694272/exit-from-while-loop-with-if-else-in-cypress)

Comment: @phileinSophos - Mikkel has just told you why **Because it's in a callback, it's asynchronous, and won't work inside the loop you have**